# R - Selecting Rows after a Certain Value in Data Frame is Found

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that has drug, date of prescription, and whether or not the particular date of prescription is associated with a gap that was determined beforehand as the columns. The values of this third column are either true/false. I am trying to create a function that outputs the rows of this data frame after a row with true in the third column is found. I only want the rows after that particular value is found, excluding that row with true. How do I go about doing this using R?

An example table looks like this:

```
 Drug    Date        Gap between Consecutive Dates? 
 Drug 1  5-18-2011               false    
 Drug 1  6-18-2011               false    
 Drug 1  10-15-2012              true     
 Drug 1  11-15-2012              false    
 Drug 1  12-15-2012              false  
 Drug 1  8-04-2015               true
 Drug 1  9-04-2015               false
 Drug 1  10-04-2015              false
```

The output should look something like this:

```
Treatment Window     Drug        Start Date              End Date
      1             Drug 1        5-18-2011              6-18-2011              
      2             Drug 1        10-15-2012             12-15-2012 
      3             Drug 1        8-04-2015              10-04-2015
```

I only want to select the rows in which 'below' is found and assign a treatment number to them based on the number of drug holidays associated with the specific drug. After each drug holiday, the treatment number increases, as the regimen may have been changed for the person taking the drug. How do I go about obtaining this output using R, if such a method in the language exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take cumulative sum of logical values `TRUE`/`FALSE` to create groups. Group by `Drug` value and get the max and min of `Date` to get start and end dates. `Window` column is created by using row number for each `Drug`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(as.logical(Gap)), 
         Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Drug, group) %>%
  summarise(Start_Date = min(Date), 
            End_date = max(Date)) %>%
  mutate(Window = row_number(), .before = 1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-group)

#  Window Drug  Start_Date End_date  
#   <int> <chr> <date>     <date>    
#1      1 Drug1 2011-05-18 2011-06-18
#2      2 Drug1 2012-10-15 2012-12-15
#3      3 Drug1 2015-08-04 2015-10-04
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Drug = c("Drug1", "Drug1", "Drug1", "Drug1", "Drug1", 
"Drug1", "Drug1", "Drug1"), Date = c("5-18-2011", "6-18-2011", 
"10-15-2012", "11-15-2012", "12-15-2012", "8-04-2015", "9-04-2015", 
"10-04-2015"), Gap = c("false", "false", "true", "false", "false", 
"true", "false", "false")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```